# Drag Drop behavior between Data table and Tree node or vice versa in JSF + Primefaces

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I know that Prime faces has not implemented drag drop behavior on Tree nodes but is there a workaround to achieve this behavior for now or is that not possible at all. I am developing a site where I would like to ability to drag and drop between :

1. Rows in the data table - This I am able to achieve.
2. Nodes within the tree node - I have not tried this yet, but does the support exist?
3. Data between table and tree

Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated. I don't necessarily need a solution but even a plausible approach would help me.

e.g Can we use drap drop feature of jquery and not Prime faces and invoke a custom ajax request to the back-end to process the drop event?

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: How did you implement #1? The only way I know exists is using jQuery and this doesn't perform server side actions.

Comment: I used primefaces draggable and droppable on each row of the data table.

Comment: what version of primefaces are you using? The Version 5.0 that I'm using already has the drag and drop features for tree node.